# Selectively delete bash history using a script when the shell is closed

Tags: bash, shell-script, command-history

I can delete history using something like this:

```
history -d 2038
```

Or use in combination with grep.

What I want is to clean the history selectively when I closed the shell:

- to delete often use commands, that are not that relevant like: ls, cd, clear (may have some patterns excluded)
- or close variations based on patterns. For example:

  1. make platform_1
  2. make platform_2
     keep only the first one.

Comment: Why not use the `HISTIGNORE` variable to ignore common commands? That's what it's for.

Comment: in some cases I want to keep just some versions and not all variations; for example I use a command 100 times, but 80 times of the use, I just change a little the filename; so in this case I just want it to keep it just once. 20 times  the used arguments differs very much I want to keep the command as it is. This way is more easy on search recall to find what I want.

Comment: Yes, that's for your second point. Doesn't `HISTIGNORE` cover your first point though? And, for your second point, I can think of ways of doing this using `~/.bash_logout` probably, but we'd have to know exactly what sort of operation you want. Keep only the first occurrence of a command? The first after a date? The last occurrence? Do you only want to clear these from the current shell history or from the stored one?

Comment: only the first occurrence; when I cycle through reverse-i-search to have less clutter